# What is the new instagram json endpoint?

Tags: json, api, instagram, instagram-api, endpoint

Instagram used to expose open data as json under the endpoint `https://www.instagram.com/<username>/?__a=1`. This changed over night, the endpoint is not available anymore. What is the new endpoint or what could be an alternative to this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am facing the same thing. :(

Comment: What error are you getting? I'm seeing that it's working at this moment for public accounts: https://www.instagram.com/github/?__a=1

Comment: @NicolaiRobles that url seems to work/not work over the past couple of days

Comment: @Alex yes. It works sometime but then again...

Comment: Meta made accessing Instagram posts very difficult. So much so that I built a SaaS to make it simple: https://behold.so — sorry for the self promotion, but the truth is there just isn't an easy answer to this any more 


Answer (score 21, accepted):

The endpoint does not exist anymore. Facebook is restricting APIs because of scandals. The data is still there of course, Instagram's frontend needs it, so the alternative right now is to scrape the page and find the json data there. Here is how I do it:

- Do an http get to to `https://www.instagram.com/<username>`.
- Look for the `script` tag which text's starts with `window._sharedData =`. You can use regular expressions or a scraping library for this.
- The rest of the text (except for the `;` at the end) is the json data you want.
- Cast the stringified json into json in order to access it like before.
- The first element in the 'ProfilePage' key in the 'entry_data' key corresponds exactly to the json returned by the old endpoint.

Here is an example using Python:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json

r = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/github/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
scripts = soup.find_all('script', type="text/javascript", text=re.compile('window._sharedData'))
stringified_json = scripts[0].get_text().replace('window._sharedData = ', '')[:-1]

json.loads(stringified_json)['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]

Out[1]:
{u'graphql': {u'user': {u'biography': u'How people build software.',
u'blocked_by_viewer': False,
...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In case you're seeking for the regex:

`<script type="text\/javascript">window[.]_sharedData = {[\s\S]*};<\/script>`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a session like instagram-scraper package does.

You don't need to provide a username and password. Below snippet will create an anonymous session.

```python
import requests
import json
try:
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
except ImportError:
    from urlparse import urlparse

BASE_URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/'
CHROME_WIN_UA = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36'

session = requests.Session()
session.headers = {'user-agent': CHROME_WIN_UA, 'Referer': BASE_URL}
session.cookies.set('ig_pr', '1')
req = session.get(BASE_URL)
session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': req.cookies['csrftoken']})

url = "https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1"
response = session.get(url, cookies="", headers={'Host': urlparse(url).hostname}, stream=False, timeout=90)
print(response.json())
```

https://github.com/arc298/instagram-scraper

Answer (score 0):

This endpoint still works but you must have valid cookies from a currently logged in session.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://www.instagram.com/<username>/?__a=1
```

works but you have to be logged in

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the object using regex, you can use this (inspired by @Emixam23)

`/(?<=<script type="text\/javascript">window[.]_sharedData = ){[\s\S]*}(?=;<\/script>)/`